# How to wrap a ul around a left floated element?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've been googling my brain out, trying to find a solution to the problem of wrapping text that may contain lists (ul) around a left floated element (figure). The bullet points is placed far out left in the floated element. I've tried to add overflow: hidden to the ul, and then the bullet points are correctly in place, but the list is no longer wrapped around the floated element.

Of course, this is an IE issue.

Some nice paint art showing what I do and do not want:

[image]

Anyone got a clue?

Comment: can you please add code or jsfiddle?

Comment: No..because the `ul` is a single element and thus is a rectangle...although it **contains** many elements it can't wrap itself around a corner.

Comment: Simple jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/karineh/stA65/, have to be run in IE to see the issue.

Comment: But I guess the answer from Paulie is the correct one anyways. Probably nothing to be done to solve this.

Comment: Below answer is fine @Karine

Comment: Unfortunately not, as this does not look good when the bullet point is more than one line of text, and I want the lines of text aligned. That's why I emphasised "good solution" in my heading btw ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `list-style-position:inside;` to your `ul`.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stA65/2/)

Comment: Would be great, but does not look good when a bullet point is longer than one line of text.

Comment: Well I guess this is the death you have to die with IE. You could assign `list-style-position:inside;` just in IE via a CSS hack, so that all the other browsers still apply `list-style-position:outside`, so that it still does look good with multiple lines in the other browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'll ask what they like :)

Comment: You are welcome. IE is just a pain in the *** sometimes, nothing you can do about it.. ;)